# Get value of a selected class vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm having a hard time trying to pass the value of a div with an active class. The user can select any tag and it toggleclass active. Only one tag can be active at a time.

```
<div class="tag-box">
     <div class="tag">Tag 1</div>
     <div class="tag active">Tag 2</div>
</div>
```

I would like to get the value who has the active class and return this value with axios like this

```
axios.post('http://localhost:4000/articles', {
   title: this.title,
   description: this.description
   tag: ????
 })
```

Since it is a not a HTML select tag, it is a bit more difficult to do it. 
Is it possible to use an if statement inside a post request?

Hope you can help me, thank you for your time!

Comment: I am not sure if this will answer your question, but you can try to add a `ref` attribute to your `.tag-box` div like: `ref="tag-box"`.
Then, do `this.$refs['tag-box'].querySelector('.tag.active')` to select the active HTMLElement of the DOM

Comment: Well, if you use Vue.js, what you could do is to save the selected tag in your `data` function. Then you can access it when you make your `axios` request like this : `tag: this.selectedTag`. I'm not sure if this is what you want. If not, please provide more details :)

Comment: Thank you guys for your response, it is solved! Like I said under the other response, I have a similar case and I want it to be a custom value, not the value in the div. Any tips? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $refs to get the element from the component, and querySelector to get the active one.

```
const tag = this.$refs.tagbox.querySelector('.active').innerText

axios.post('http://localhost:4000/articles', {
   title: this.title,
   description: this.description,
   tag
 })
```

```html
<div ref='tagbox' class="tag-box">
     <div class="tag">Tag 1</div>
     <div class="tag active">Tag 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted thank you very much!
However, I have a similar case when I don't want it to take the value the div tag (here tag1) but a custom one. How can I do?

Comment: @blickblick Put the value in an attribute. `<div class="tag" myvalue='tag1'>Tag 1</div>`.  Then use `element.getAttribute('myvalue')`.

Comment: Where should I use `element.getAttribute('myvalue')`? I mean how can I access the value of the selected tag?

Comment: `this.$refs.tagbox.querySelector('.active').getAttribute('myvalue')`

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much :)